# SQL query for selecting something where count is greater than or less than something

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, count, having

I am trying to write a SQLite query to extract the **females** purchasing **Product A** in the last 12 months, and prior to this date, **Product B** was purchased regularly (at least 5 purchases in the preceding 8 months), and post this date, **Product B** stopped being purchased.

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
gender = 'Female' and
product_name='Product A' and
tran_date > '15/09/2019' and

((SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
product_name='Product B' and
tran_date<'15/09/2019' and
tran_date>'15/01/2019') HAVING COUNT(*)>=5) and

((SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
product_name='Product B' and
tran_date>'15/09/2019') HAVING COUNT(*)==0)
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error (near "HAVING": syntax error)
Error Code: 1
```

The 3 sub-queries for the 3 sub-parts work fine without the `HAVING COUNT` part:

```
--Look for the females purchasing Product A in the last 12 months 
SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
gender = 'Female' and
product_name='Product A' and
tran_date > '15/09/2019'

--prior to this date, Product B was purchased regularly (at least 5 purchases in the preceding 8 months)
SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
class_name='Product B' and
tran_date<'15/09/2019' and
tran_date>'15/01/2019'

--post this date, Product B stopped being purchased
SELECT member_id,tran_date FROM Table WHERE
class_name='Product B' and
tran_date>'15/09/2019'
```

I'm just not able to combine them. How do I do that?

Also, as an absolute beginner in SQL, would the query need to be edited to be run on Postgre SQL?

Comment: `15/09/2019` is not a data, but 15 divided by 9 divided by 2019, and gives 0.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried putting the date in quotes, like so `'15/09/2019'`, but I get the same error.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share some sample data with expected output based on the sample. Thanks!!

Comment: @Kristada673 . . . `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is highly suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `HAVING` without grouping (`GROUP BY`), that is why it gives error. Because it does not know according to what to count the records; id, date, name? First you need to identify member ids that fit in your count condition and put them in where clause of your main select statement. Check code below for your last 2 queries. These can work on PostgreSQL as well without edit.

If your `tran_date` column is datetime, use a format such as `'15/01/2019 00:00:00.000'`. If the column is a type of char, then be sure all values are in same format. Otherwise, correct them.

```
SELECT member_id, tran_date
FROM Table
WHERE tran_date BETWEEN '15/01/2019' AND '15/09/2019'
AND member_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(member_id) AS member_id FROM Table
                    WHERE tran_date BETWEEN '15/01/2019' AND '15/09/2019'
                    AND class_name = 'Product B'
                    GROUP BY member_id
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5)

SELECT member_id, tran_date
FROM Table
WHERE tran_date > '15/01/2019'
AND member_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(member_id) AS member_id FROM Table
                    WHERE tran_date > '15/01/2019'
                    AND class_name = 'Product B'
                    GROUP BY member_id
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by member_id` and set all the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
select member_id
from tablename
where gender = 'Female' and tran_date > '2019-01-15'
group by member_id
having sum(tran_date > '2019-09-15' and product_name = 'Product A') > 0
   and sum(tran_date < '2019-09-15' and product_name = 'Product B') >= 5
   and sum(tran_date > '2019-09-15' and product_name = 'Product B') = 0
```

Note the only valid comparable date format in SQLite is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Your query only gives the ids, but he probably needs other columns as well. He wants all the records whose ids made x amount of purchases.

Comment: @highlytrainedbadger read the question: *...to extract the females purchasing...*

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I did not understand his desired output.